# JavaScript change object value through reference/link/etc

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change object's value not directly?

For example

```
a = {x: 5}

b = a.x
b = 100

a.x // => 5
```

I'd like to get 100, but actually, `a.x` is still 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the number as object, and not as literal:

```
a = {x: {v: 5}}

b = a.x
b.v = 100

a.x​​.v // => 100
```

Answer (score 5):

Not like you are going it, no. You can do this though:

```
a = { x: 5 };
b = a;
b.x = 100;
a.x // => 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. All references to object are equal, no matter if it first one or not. However, `a.x` is not an object, it is property of object `a`, so with `b = a.x` you copy a value of that property, that happens to be a simple number to `b`. `b` is not linked to `a` in any way and assigning something else to `b` will do nothing to `a`. You need to assign `b = a`, then you can modify property `.x` of object referenced by both variables as either `a.x` or `b.x`.

Comment: No he can't, you're thinking of changing properties of object and he wants assignment by reference. You can't change what a variable is assigned to (unless you have that variable itself of course) in javascript, object or not.

Comment: I don't see "I want assignment by reference" here, so I answer what he can do.

Comment: It's clear from his example. Merely adding `b =& a.x` in a language that actually supports it would make it all work.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to achieve this in JavaScript. 5 is of a Number type and it's a value type. There is no way to access it through reference unlike Function, Object or Array.

Comment: It does not matter what the value assigned to `b` is. What he is asking is to make `b` a reference to the same storage used for `a.x`.